# Hardware problems, can I reinstall OS?

Tags: hardware

I have managed to break physically break my internal screen on my laptop, I have a sony vio E17 which is connected to a external screen. Yes I have unplugged the internal screen. My main and root account is inaccessible since the latest update.

The question is, can I format and reinstall Ubuntu with a external screen?

#### UPDATE #1

To clarify; the external screen is used as primary and not secondary. But yes I can access BIOS and bootable disks.

Seems like I am ready to procced!

Comment: What would suggest that you couldn't do this?

Comment: If you are worried about something going wrong you can image your hard drive before you start. You could also install Linux onto a USB drive and after it is fully working copy it to your hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

An answer exists here for [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/294061/installing-windows-on-a-laptop-using-an-external-monitor-main-display-broken) but if it's possible for Windows then it should be possible for Ubuntu.

**Note:** make sure you're able to see the BIOS in the external monitor when you restart the computer, otherwise it can be really tricky depending on the manufacturer.